# GNU make on Mint (Ubuntu Linux) Simple Pattern rule gives: "no targets"

Tags: pattern-matching, gnu-make

What is wrong with this Makefile?
I have three files with a .z suffix and I want to make 3 files of the same name with a .x suffix.
(I am trying to get a GNU make pattern rule to work; any pattern rule... :(! )

```
ls *.z
doll.z  dummy.z  puppet.z

 cat -t all.mk
.SUFFIXES: 
.SUFFIXES: .x .z
%.x:^I%.z 
^Iecho 'Pre-req' $< makes target $@
^Icp $< $@

make  -f all.mk 
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

Comment: You can say `make -f all.mk doll.x puppet.x`, for example. But your makefile has no explicit rules (try `info make explicit`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pattern rule is a *template*.  It tells make, "if you want to build a target like this and there's no explicit rule to do it, here's how to do it".

A pattern rule isn't a directive: it doesn't say "go search the filesystem for all possible targets that could be built using this pattern and build them".

So, you've created a template make *could* use to build `.x` targets from `.z` prerequisites, but, just as the error message says, you haven't actually asked make to build anything.

To get make to build something you have to ask for something to be built.  One way is via the command line, as the comment above says:

```
make -f all.mk doll.x
```

Now make knows you want to build `doll.x` so it will go looking for ways to do that, and find your pattern rule.  Or you can put it into the makefile itself, like this (`all` is the traditional target name for "build the things" but you can use whatever you like):

```
.PHONY: all
all: doll.x  dummy.x  puppet.x
```

Or you can even determine what to build dynamically, like this:

```
.PHONY: all
all: $(patsubst %.z,%.x,$(wildcard *.z))
```

Comment: Great answer. Espcially the part about the .PHONY target. that is what I am aiming for eventually.